# How to get a border on top of another border in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a navigation bar, where by default it has a `border-top` of a certain color, and when either hovered or active, I wanted another color to go on top of it.

Is there any method that I can make this to work?

I've tried:

- `absolute`
- `z-index`

but neither works for me.

```css
.navbar {
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul,li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul {
    min-height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
    border-top: 5px solid #d1d064;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul > li {
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 150px;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    color: #737373;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul > li.active {
    border-top: thick solid #0F9E5E;
}
.navbar > .main-nav {
    max-width: 1480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hover.css/2.1.0/css/hover-min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>  
<nav class="navbar">
        <div class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="active hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="hvr-overline-from-center"><a href="#">Second</a></li>
                <li class="hvr-overline-from-center"><a href="#">Third</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

*EDIT: Accidentally attached the wrong code in, I've fixed it now.*

Comment: You mean you want two borders? Or just one in a different color? Two borders can't be done normally, but you could add an extra 'border' by using  `::before` or `::after` pseudo-elements, or by using a box-shadow. If you want just a different color, that currently doesn't work, because the selector with `.active` has [higher specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) than the one with `:hover`.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in the post. I wanted when its active and hovered, the border color of that navigation changes while other remained the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a border to the `li` which is transparent, then change its color based on being active or hovered

*Note, I cleaned up your code some, and remove the `margin-top: -5px;` on your `li` since it was hiding the first items top border*

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul {
  min-height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul > li {
  border-top: thick solid transparent;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 150px;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul > li a {
  display: block;
  color: #737373;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul > li.active {
  border-top-color: #0F9E5E;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul > li:hover {
  border-top-color: #fff;
}
.navbar > .main-nav {
  max-width: 1480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Second</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Third</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll keep this in mind next time I do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `box-shadow`
Either default or `inset`

Example:

```
box-shadow: 0 -10px 0 0 red;
```

or

```
box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 0 0 red;
```

or a combination

```
box-shadow: 0 -10px 0 0 red, 10px 0 0 blue, inset 10px 0 0 green;
```

Combined with border, you should get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making your `<li>` tags `.active`, you can style `<a>` tags to take whole space of their parents and put (active) border on it. Then on `:hover`, put another border on `<li>` tag - it will make it appear on top. To avoid size jumping, give your `<li>` some transparent border, of the same size as the one you give on `:hover`

```
a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
a.active {
  border-top: thick solid #0F9E5E;
}
li {
  border-top: thick solid transparent;
}
li:hover, li:active {
  border-top: thick solid red; // color of your choice
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin-top and add !important for the border style on elements li.active and li:hover

check this snippet

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul {
  padding-top: 1px;
  min-height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  border-top: 7px solid #d1cf82;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: -1;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul > li {
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 150px;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  color: #737373;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul > li.active {
  border-top: thick solid #0F9E5E !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul > li:hover {
  border-top: thick solid #fff !important;
}
.navbar > .main-nav {
  max-width: 1480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Second</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Third</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help, but is it possible for the green color to overlap the yellow color?

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly u mean

Answer (score 0):

```
    .navbar {
      background-color: #ecf0f1;
    }
    .navbar > .main-nav > ul,
    li {
      list-style-type: none;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .navbar > .main-nav > ul {
      padding-top: 1px;
      min-height: 60px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #ecf0f1;
      border-top: 7px solid #d1cf82;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    .navbar > .main-nav > ul > li {
      text-align: center;
      min-width: 150px;
          }
    .navbar > .main-nav > ul > li > a {
      display: block;
      color: #737373;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 800;
    }
    .navbar > .main-nav > ul > li{
    border-top:7px solid red;
    position:relative;
}
.navbar > .main-nav > ul > li:hover:before, .navbar > .main-nav > ul > li.active:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top: -14px;
    left:0;
    border-top:7px solid green;
 }
    .navbar > .main-nav {
      max-width: 1480px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="main-nav">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Second</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Third</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```